# Resizing a frame and its components when using NULL Layout

Tags: java, swing, layout

When using null layout, how to resize components?

I mean their position and size. I know that using layout managers we need not take care of this issue.
But my requirement is *to move components in the panel*. So I ought to use null layout.

Please let me know if you have ideas regarding finding new locations to place components on resize of the frame.

Comment: You have conflicting requirements since to have your components resize with change in top level container you'll want to use a combination of layout managers, but on the other hand if you need to exactly specify the location of components, you may use null layout. I think that to answer this question you must clarify your requirements to a much greater degree and post them here. What *exactly* are you trying to do?

Comment: is it required that you use a null layout?

Comment: -1, Your requirement is to "change position and size". That is exactly the job of a layout manager, so you should NOT be using a null layout. Beyond that we can't give you a recommendation on what layout manager to use since you haven't given a requirement about how the size/position changes as the frame is resized.

Answer (score 3):

[Doing Without a Layout Manager](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html) tutorial may help, although it is recommended that you use a layout manager, if at all possible.

**Recommendations**

1. Either use a layout manager, or
2. Register a [ComponentListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ComponentListener.html) and manually resize/position components when a [resize event](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ComponentListener.html#componentResized%28java.awt.event.ComponentEvent%29) occurs.

The labor incurred with the latter approach may be enormous, and hence why using a layout manager comes highly recommended. Another, albeit cheap alternative (which I'm sure violates your requirements), is to invoke [`setResizable(false)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setResizable%28boolean%29) on your `JFrame`.

Answer (score 0):

for a component to be displayed in a null layout, they must of the bounds set on the component. They need a position(x,y) and a width/height

Comment: Thanks for stating what is already obvious to the original poster, meverett.

Comment: I really against AbsoluteLayout, but answer to the question +1