# Automatic Scale JPanel --swing window resized

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel, scale

I use null layout.

On resizing the swing window, the JPanel doesn't get resized to fit according to new swing window size.

Suggest any function or other way to obviate.

Comment: What is the reason for null layout?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resizing a frame and its components when using NULL Layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6459001/resizing-a-frame-and-its-components-when-using-null-layout)

Comment: The best way I can think of is providing values relative to the parent `Container` instead of providing constant values For Example `jTextField.setLocation(jPanel.getX() + 10, jPanel.getY() + 30);`, I guess such code can give you the desired output along with using [ComponentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/componentlistener.html)

Comment: you are experiencing the desastrous effect of _not_ using a LayoutManager - the solution is obvious :-)

Answer (score 0):

I actually did this once

My method was this

I first set a smaller size window  then I set the null layout and then set the size of a component, lets say a JButton. Then I get the screensize for my computer

```
Dimension screensize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
```

I then calculate what is the ratio of my smaller jframe to my computer's fullscreensize
a ratio for width and another for height   so if my fullscreen 1000x800  and my smaller size jframe is 500x400  i know ratiow and ratioh is 1/2   so when window resizes  set jbutton size to 1/2 times larger (do all the calculation of ratio and setting sizes in the paint method) (when screen resizes, it will automatically called paint()) or you can call repaint()

Sorry  I do not have the older code can't post it here.  My last HDD was broke.